# Error when Installing a Package in Laravel 8.15 and php 8.0.2

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting the error when installing a laravel Package.
Please help me out. I am using **PHP Version 8.0.2** and **Laravel Framework 8.15.0**

```
$ composer require hnhdigital-os/laravel-number-converter
```

here is the error

**

> Using version ^1.1 for hnhdigital-os/laravel-number-converter
> ./composer.json has been updated Running composer update
> hnhdigital-os/laravel-number-converter Loading composer repositories
> with package information Updating dependencies Your requirements could
> not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

> ```
> - spatie/laravel-permission is locked to version 3.17.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
> - spatie/laravel-permission 3.17.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
> ```

Problem 2

> ```
> - yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle is locked to version v9.14.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
> - yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle v9.14.1 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
> ```

Problem 3

> ```
> - dompdf/dompdf v0.8.6 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v0.8.7 requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.8 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.8.6].
> - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf is locked to version v0.8.7 and an update of this package was not requested. Installation failed,
> ```
>
> reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original
> content.

**

Comment: The error message isn't obvious enough? Given packages doesn't support php 8.

Comment: If packages were working before in PHP 8 but composer is now refusing to update, then you can try the flag `--ignore-platform-req php` to ignore php version specific errors. However be aware that the packages may not fully work in PHP 8

Comment: Thank you my dear. Let me go back to the previous php version.